# Sync contacts between different account types

Tags: contacts, accounts, samsung-galaxy-s-8, contact-photo

I have two account types on my phone: Exchange and Google.

I'd like to sync the two, to make sure that an account that exists only in Google exists in Exchange as well, and vice-versa. I'd also like to sync the photos (in my case, the Exchange photos are all very old and low quality, and I'd like to fix that).

I couldn't find a way to do this using the standard Contacts app on my phone (Galaxy S8). I'm guessing I'd need to use some kind of app for this, but most searches yield backup-restore applications which seem to be designed to, well, backup to a file / restore from a file (which isn't what I need), and completely ignore the photo problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research it seems it's impossible to do this using stock Android software.

Sync can be done with Contacts Optimizer. This should transfer basic contact information between account types, however leaves out picture information (at least I've found it to copy low-res photos only).

So I've tried apps like Sync.ME and CoSy for pictures (at least to get the latest info from social media sites). The former was a miss - it doesn't actually store the downloaded FB information as part of the existing contacts. The latter seemed to work much better, and actually stored high-res photos as part of the contact information.